# Move ACF Fields between Post Title and Block Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

Please help I'm wasting days trying to do this.
I can't believe it seems so difficult.

All I want to do is move these two AFC fields that are set to always be on every post above the block editor, but below the title and slug.

[image: Single Post Editor]

Comment: One hacky way to do that is via Javascript (load a editor.js file and tweak the DOM) See an example of implementation here : [codepen](https://codepen.io/kisaure/pen/wvjmKyY)

Answer (score 0):

Cheers,

do I see it right: You have normal ACF fields (no ACF Block) and you want it to be displayed after the title? If you want this, just to show it with a higher priority in the backend, I also couldn't find a solution for this.

But anyway, where it will show up in the frontend, is managed by the php file, which reads the fields. So it's just an optical thing.

Few other approaches, that might be an option (maybe also not, depending on what exactly you are aiming at the end)

- Instead of using ACF fields, use the post-thumbnail and the custom post class, given by WordPress by default
- If you have ACF Pro, you can create ACF Blocks and drop them everywhere you want
- Go with the wordpress default blocks and create block-patterns. If the picture and text are used for example to create the site header, you can visually edit them and loading css to front- and backend, so editor and website look almost same. That's pretty sweet from the user-friendliness side.
- When you create the field, you can set the position. Theoretically there is the option for "after title, before content. But sadly it's not working. But you can put it to the posts sidebar. Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe a compromise.

Hope there was something helpful

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I can create a block for it which would solve this issue, but then I can't stop a client removing this intial block by mistake, which is why I wanted to fix this first and then run blocks afterwards. Plus if I create a block for it, I will need to get the image data from within the_content(); (and for this particular block type only) so I can loop the data else where on the site and on the category page in my excerpt tile. I could also use the featured image as you mentioned, but i wanted to find a way to have all the content stacked in the main window on the left.

Comment: For locking Blocks, there are these build in options: 
- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#locking

- https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/08/locking-blocks-in-wordpress-5-9/

apart from this, I can understand your wish, as I searched as well quite a while for a solution, but ended up with the workaraunds I proposed in here